# Разница в коммутации каналов, пакетов, сообщений

Tags: сеть

Например я передаю файл используя модель OSI. 
он должен пройти по всем 7ми уровням. 
на канальном уровне коммутация каналов 
на транспортном - пакетов

Как файл должен определить по какой технологии передаваться, и обязательно ли он должен использовать все 3 вида?

Comment: А как передать файл, используя модель OSI? Семиуровневая модель -- чисто теоретическое построение. А вот реализация слоёв стека -- дело операционной системы. Приходилось встречать жалобы на WinNT? что эти слои в реализации несколько перепутаны (точнее не помню -- давно это было). Хотя нормально -- фрейм протокола 2 уровня (ethernet, ppp и т.д.). Внутри него -- фрейм IP, внутри -- фрейм tcp-udp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Файл - это уже абстракция файловой системы. Файл, это, фактически, отметка Ос самой себе, что вот эта вот кучка байтов, находящяяся на определенном треке\цилиндре жесткого диска, являются некоей отдельной сущностью, к которой может производиться обращение, как к логической (ну и физической, раз уж на то пошло), единице. 
Файл вообще не решает как он будет передаваться.   
Вы сами организуете передачу байт. 
Если вы передаете файл используя определенное API (к примеру, сокеты там, или пайпы), то вы работаете на высоком уровне. Скорее всего ваши данные (из вашего файла) будут засунуты в tcp, потом в ip пакет, потом еще во что-то, и под конец уже в Ethernet Frame.   Ethernet Frame, в свою очередь, будет засунут целиком либо по частям, по DMA, в буфер вашей Ethernet-карты (x26 модема или что у вас там), либо по байтику будет запихиваться в соотв. регистры.  Запись в регистры будет инициировать возбуждение физических сигналов на выходах порта вашей сетевой карты. 
Поэтому как айл будет передаваться, зависит только от Вас, того, какое API\технологию передачи данных вы используете.
Сокеты и прочие ребята - уже, как правило, высокий уровень абстракции, работающий "над" или "по") TCP\IP. А это уже протокол сами знаете какого уровня пакетной передачи данных. 
Чтобы контролировать то что "ниже", нужно соотвественно и спускаться ниже, т.е. на уровень вызовов драйверов и иже с ним.